# Xpath finding in the html code

Tags: regex, r, html, xpath

I am trying to get the Xpath of the following. I am trying to get the name of the location. 'London' from this div tag. I use \h4\a as Xpath but i am unable to do so. Any suggestions on how to specify correct Xpath?

```
 <h4><a href="www.example.com" tile="Click here">London</a></h4>
```

Comment: maybe, this will //h4/a  ? :)

Comment: Are you using a specific language?

Comment: i am using R and it has functionality for xpath.

Comment: here is the code  plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//h4/a", xmlValue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**XML**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) package, applying XPath to grab the text from that node.

```
library(XML)
res <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(doc), '//h4/a', xmlValue)
```

Or the shorthand version:

```
res <- doc['//h4/a/text()'][[1]]
```